# Break loop after x time if waiting too much

Tags: c, loops

> I am using C, in code blocks for reference. My code is as follows:

```
while(1)
{   
   char ch;   
   ch = _getch();  
   MyFunction1(ch);   
}
```

end of code.

So the code waits until there is any input from keyboard, and enters the single character automatic.

My problem is, how I make it so if there is no input for 1/4 of a second to run MyFuction2() instead of MyFunction1() .

Comment: If this `getch` from `curses.h`, then it is capable of returning error on timeout. Check for it and break from the loop (you need it to be in half-delay mode)

Comment: it is not from `curses.h` so I don't truly understand what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do as the following.

```
while (true) {
    SleepEx((1/4)*1000, true);
    if (_kbhit()) {
        MyFunction1(_getch());
    }
    else {
        MyFunction2();
    }
}
```

Comment: unidentified `SleepEx`, sorry, am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi, Drogon. SleepEx is the basic Windows API. Just add #include <windows.h> or write the other sleep function if you use other OS.